# WPF: Свечение вокруг окна и его последствия

Tags: c#, wpf

Везде в интернете (например, [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13367249/wpf-window-shadow-effect) и [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14730311/wpf-borderless-window-with-shadow-vs2012-style)) написано, что для создания эффекта свечения окна надо создать внутренний элемент с отступом на `n` пикселей и собственным свечением в радиусе `n` пикселей.

Пример создания красной подсветки:

```
<Window>
    <Border Margin="7">
        <Border.Effect>
            <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0" BlurRadius="7" Color="Red"/>
        </Border.Effect>
    </Border>
    <!-- content -->
</Window>
```

Однако у такого способа есть ряд недостатков:

1. При создании скриншота окна (`Alt`+`PrintScreen`) в кадр так же захватывается само свечение и часть рабочего стола за ним.
2. При стыковке окна к левой/правой части рабочего стола  оно так же находится на расстоянии от границ экрана, поскольку окно пытается подстроить свои размеры с учетом отступа для свечения.

Насколько я знаю, последние версии Visual Studio так же созданы при помощи WPF, однако там все эти косяки не наблюдаются, не смотря на наличие эффекта той же самой подсветки. Почему? Или это я что то делаю не так?

Answer (score 1):

Несмотря на то, что вопрос задан очень давно, может кому-то пригодиться.

1-ый вопрос очень спорный.. если и есть способ кроме того, что я напишу далее, я о нем не знаю, а тот что я опишу маловероятно будет должным образом работать.
Можно создать глобальный хук клавиатуры и отлавливать событие нажатия клавиш Printscreen и во время этого на мгновения убирать отступ между бордером для свечения и его содержимым(остальным содержимым), но скриншот экрана может выполнится еще до отлова события хуком, так что можно попытаться сделать блокировку Printscreen'а, как это реализовано в AutoHotKey если привязать к какой-либо клавише Hotkey, и вызывать нажатие клавиши сразу после скрытия отступа. Как блокировать нажатие клавиш придется искать отдельно.

2-ой вопрос полегче и можно сделать всё элегантно, в частности использованием паттерна [MVVM](https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/22.1.php). В VM окна добавить свойство типа Margin, возвращающее значение зависящее от текущего состояния окна и обновляемое по событию Window.StateChanged. Точно также можно сделать к примеру округленные уголки окна которые в максимизированном состоянии окна становятся острыми, заполняя пространство которое иначе могло быть пустым, что выглядело бы неподобающе.
Далее показан пример именно для округленных уголков, но по аналогии делается и свойство отступа.

```
public CornerRadius WindowCornerRadius
    {
        get
        {
            if (_parentWindow.WindowState == WindowState.Maximized)
            {
                return new CornerRadius(0);
            }
            else
            {
                return new CornerRadius(5);
            }
        }
    }
    public CornerRadius WindowChromeCornerRadius
    {
        get
        {
            if (_parentWindow.WindowState == WindowState.Maximized)
            {
                return new CornerRadius(0);
            }
            else
            {
                return new CornerRadius(5, 5, 0, 0);
            }
        }
    }

    private void WindowStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OnPropertyChanged("WindowCornerRadius");
        OnPropertyChanged("WindowChromeCornerRadius");
    }
```

Не забываем подписать метод на событие window.StateChanged и использовать в нем OnPropertyChanged(*название свойств*);